# What does the @ character do in a pth

Tags: c#, path

What does the "@" mean/do?  Where is the documentation on a "@" character in the path?

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"FakeData.xml", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: It makes sure you don't have to escape every backslash (for example) but instead just lets you enter the normal URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you prefix a string literal with the @ symbol, you have created what is termed a verbatim string. Using verbatim strings, you disable the processing of a literal’s escape characters and print out a string as is. This can be most useful when working with strings representing directory and network paths. Therefore, rather than making use of \escape characters, you can simply write the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"C:\MyApp\bin\Debug");
```

Also note that verbatim strings can be used to preserve white space for strings that flow over multiple lines.

```
string myLongString = @"This is a very 
very 
    very 
        long string"; 
Console.WriteLine(myLongString);
```

Using verbatim strings, you can also directly insert a double quote into a literal string by doubling the "token.

```
Console.WriteLine(@"""");
```

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

C# supports two forms of string literals: regular string literals and **verbatim** string literals.

A regular string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes, as in "hello", and may include both simple escape sequences (such as \t for the tab character) and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences.

**A verbatim string literal** consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim string literal may span multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't in the path, it's saying that the string should be taken literally.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

For example:

```
string a = "hello, world";                  // hello, world
string b = @"hello, world";               // hello, world
string c = "hello \t world";               // hello     world
string d = @"hello \t world";               // hello \t world
string e = "Joe said \"Hello\" to me";      // Joe said "Hello" to me
string f = @"Joe said ""Hello"" to me";   // Joe said "Hello" to me
string g = "\\\\server\\share\\file.txt";   // \\server\share\file.txt
string h = @"\\server\share\file.txt";      // \\server\share\file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It means "verbatim" or take the string [literally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  `@` is commonly used when setting up file paths:

`@"C:\MyFolder\file.txt"`

Otherwise you have to escape the backslashes:

`"C:\\MyFolder\\file.txt"`

It's usually helpful, but it can also be a bother.  I tend to combine `@` with string concatenation when I'm dealing with double quotes.

```
        string a = "\"";
        //string b = @"\"";//does not compile
        string c = "\"" + @"C:\Path\File.txt" + "\"";//useful for outputting to command line

        Console.WriteLine("prints quote {0} prints path surrounded by quotes {1}",a, c);
```

Comment: Both great answers but alas SO only allows one answer.  Still gets an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

"@" is **verbatim**  string.  It's used for string literal. use cases of file path which u need to escape the double slash. It writes exact text. No escaping needed.

for eg : s`tring path =@"c:\demo\files\txt2.text";`